# Add image and text to list in html from JSON

Tags: javascript, html, image, list

My use case is to add image and a text dynamically to list. All I have is JSON (extracted from DB as result set). The JSON structure is as mentioned below:

```
[{"Comment":"Test","FilePath":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/20130725153841.JPEG"},{"Comment":"Image List","FilePath":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/20130725160020.JPEG"}]
```

So, in my java script, I append this list to a HTML body through the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
    var data =     [{"Comment":"Test","FilePath":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/20130725153841.JPEG"},{"Comment":"Image List","FilePath":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/20130725160020.JPEG"}]
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.Comment + '</li>');
    });
    $('<ul/>', {        
        html: items.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');
    });
</script>
```

Here, I am trying to bring an image (whose filepath is available in the JSON) to the list. So, the list should contain image (may be a smaller one - I shall use styling for this) and the comment side by side.

Please can someone help?

EDIT:

I tried this: I am building the list runtime.. So, i tried using

before val.comment.. it doesnt seem to work. Any words on this?

Comment: Your code looks almost finished. What problem do you have which prevents you to add the image ?

Comment: By the way a precision : there's no [JSON](http://json.org) here.

Comment: My question is: how to add image to the list dynamically? I am building the list runtime.. So, i tried using <img src=""> before val.comment.. it doesnt seem to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show image with each list item you should have to add `img tag` in your list item. The JS code should be like below:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '"><img src="' + val.FilePath + '" />' + val.Comment + '</li>');
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of the JSONArray that we receive in the JS VAR?

Comment: @HariprasauthRamamoorthy, no there will be no limit.

Answer (score 0):

In your items.push add the `<img>` tag and output the value from your `FilePath` field:

```
items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val.Comment + '<img src="' + val.FilePath +'" alt="" />' + '</li>');
```

Comment: Is there a limit to the size of the JSONArray that we receive in the JS VAR?